# JavaFX: How to clear a DatePicker value

Tags: javafx

How to clear DatePicker value if textfield is clear?
I known, that I can do it by:

```
datePicker.setValue(null);
```

But I need listener for textfield in datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a ChangeListener to the textProperty of your TextField.

something like:

```
textField.textProperty().isEmpty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, 
                final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue) {
           if (newValue){
              datePicker.setValue(null);
            }
      }
{);
```

Comment: Yes.
datePicker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                                String oldValue, String newValue) {

                System.out.println(newValue);

                if(newValue.equals("")) {
                    datePicker.setValue(null);
                }

            }
        });

Comment: textField.textProperty().isEmpty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
               @Override
      public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, 
                final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue) {
           if (newValue){
              datePicker.setValue(null);
            }
      }
            });